# What is the etymology behind 角色?

Tags: etymology

personally it's easier for me to study words/phrases to understand the roots, but I have an interesting word that I can't figure out why it was derived from

角色

Corner and Color... how did that become to mean someone's Role?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[脚色](https://wuu.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E8%84%9A%E8%89%B2)

> "脚色" /juésè/ is often written as "角色"/juésè/

> 演员根据[**脚**]本演绎各[**色**]人物 - The actors play various characters according to the script.

[脚本](https://baike.baidu.com/item/%E8%84%9A%E6%9C%AC/1591252) = script

各色人物 = various characters

脚色/ 角色 = role

Note:

脚 = base

本 = script

As far as I know, 角色 is the more commonly used word for "role" than 脚色 for the general public

Comment: 主角 or 主脚? Here is a discussion about them. https://www.sohu.com/a/494294498_121080240

Comment: It said: 最初， “脚色”与“角色”的意思是相同的 - I suppose 角色 is not a mistake for 脚色

Comment: But your first quote says otherwise :)

Comment: What's your take on this? https://www.chinanews.com.cn/hwjy/news/2010/03-23/2186104.shtml  It seems to suggest that 脚色 predates 脚本. It does of course agree with you that 角色 is a later variant.

Comment: @StumpyJoePete Check out this article - "在这里，脚色与角色的意思就已经发生了变化，**“脚色”指的是戏剧行当**，是根据戏班演员的技艺工种进行区别的；**而“角色”则是指代剧中的各类任务形象**。例如著名的戏剧《张协状元》中，张协、贫女、汉元帝、王昭君等人物是角色，而扮演他们的“生”、“旦”、“末”则是“脚色”，一个“脚色”可以扮演很多“角色”，反之则不能。(https://www.sohu.com/a/494294498_121080240#)". Also, you shall check out the dictionary for the definition and usage of 脚(https://www.zdic.net/hans/%E8%84%9A) and 角(https://www.zdic.net/hans/%E8%84%9A)

Comment: @StumpyJoePete In the Classic Chinese plays, each role had to act in a certain way based on the 造形/型(脚色) - 生/旦/净/末/丑, the role(角色) called for.  Note that "生旦净末丑"是中国京剧戏曲里的**人物角色行当(造形/型)分类**, 而不是戏曲里的**人物角色**.

Answer (score 0):

角 - 演员(actor) - 名角(famous actor).

色 - 种类(type) - 各色用品(Various types of supplies); 形形色色(all kinds).

角色 - 指演员在戏剧中所扮演的人物(role or character in a novel/movie/play), 或某一类型的人物(a/certain type/kind of person).

- 在電影中他演什麼角色? - What "**role/character/persona**" does he play in the movie?
- 他是什麼角色竟敢替你出頭? - What kind of "**character**" is he who dares to stand up for you?